# Сортировка по отзывам из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, сортировка, codeigniter, order

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как реализовать сортировку по популярности (отзывам) из двух таблиц. При том чтобы отображались все записи из первой таблицы.

К примеру есть таблица *me_cars*. При выводе можно менять сортировку (asc, desc):

```
$order == "desc") {
    $this->db->order_by('me_cars.item_title', 'desc');
}
```

В примере выше все работает как нужно, все записи (5шт) отображаются и сортируются по заголовку.

Вопрос собственно в том, как можно отсортировать по отзывам, которые находятся в другой таблице *me_cars_reviews* при этом показать все записи (5шт) из первой таблицы, но учитывая сортировку из второй таблицы?

Таблица **me_cars**

```
| item_id |  item_title |
+---------+-------------+
|    1    |  Title item |
+---------+-------------+
|    2    |  Title item |
+---------+-------------+
|    3    |  Title item |
+---------+-------------+
|    4    |  Title item |
+---------+-------------+
|    5    |  Title item |
+---------+-------------+
```

**item_id** - ID автомобиля

**item_title** - название автомобиля

Таблица **me_cars_reviews**

```
| review_id | review_itemid | review_overall |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     1     |       4       |       8        |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     2     |       4       |       6        |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     3     |       1       |       7        |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     4     |       4       |       3        |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     5     |       4       |       1        |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

**review_id** - ID отзыва

**review_itemid** - ID автомобиля из первой таблицы

**review_overall** - оценка

Попробовал сделать так:

```
$order == "popular") {
    $this->db->select('me_cars.item_id,me_cars_reviews.review_overall,pt_reviews.review_itemid');
    $this->db->select_avg('pt_reviews.review_overall', 'overall');
    $this->db->order_by('overall', 'desc');
    $this->db->group_by('me_cars.item_id');
    $this->db->join('me_cars_reviews', 'me_cars.item_id = me_cars_reviews.review_itemid');
}
```

При данной реализации все работает (сортирует и отображает), но отображает только те записи которые присутствуют во второй таблице me_cars_reviews, т.е. выводит только 2 записи (где *review_itemid* = 1 и 4). Пример:

**1 запись** (4 item_id) (по наибольшим оценкам)

**2 запись** (1 item_id)

больше ничего не показывает

Необходимо вывести все 5 записей (>) из первой таблицы, но учитывая вторую, т.е. на выходе должно получится так:

**1 запись** (4 item_id)

**2 запись** (1 item_id)

**3 запись** - остальные без отзывов

**4 запись** - остальные без отзывов

**5 запись** - остальные без отзывов

и т.д. (если в таблице me_cars больше записей)

p.s. 5 записей просто для примера. В таблице может быть 100, 200 и т.д.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

[Можно вот так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b378/10/0):

```
SELECT
  c.`item_title` AS Title,
  COALESCE(SUM(r.`review_overall`),0) AS Overall
FROM
  me_cars AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  me_cars_reviews AS r
  ON c.`item_id` = r.`review_itemid`
GROUP BY
  c.`item_id`
ORDER BY
  Overall DESC
```

Если "баллы" нужно не сумировать, а просто подсчитать количество оценок - в третей строчке запроса `SUM` меняем на `COUNT`.

Чтобы разобраться, почитайте [памятку по объединениям](http://majestio.info/viewtopic.php?id=26) - когда-то для себя делал.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это преобразовать в CI3 запрос? Не могу понять, что необходимо заменить в моем коде.

Comment: Увы, данный фрэймворк я не знаю. Посмотрите примеры, например тут - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821687/in-codeigniter-how-do-i-do-a-join-with-a-where-clause

Comment: В вашем коде в селекте указано явно поле `me_cars_reviews.review_overall`. Это не должно быть правильным, т.к. по нему должны идти групповые операции.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_title FROM me_cars mc
LEFT JOIN me_cars_reviews mcr ON mc.item_id =  mcr.review_itemid
ORDER BY mcr.review_overall DESC
```

skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html - очень понятная статья о join-ах